# "Засмотрели" в значении "принялись смотреть"

Tags: значение-слов

Приемлемо ли такое употребление?
Или же "засмотрели до дыр" является единственным возможным вариантом?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, "засмотрели" нельзя использовать в значении "принялись (начали) смотреть", даже в разговорном варианте нельзя.

Answer (score 2):

Помимо "засмотреть до дыр" видеокассету (?), есть слово "засмотреться", но и ему приставка не придаёт смысла начала действия.

Бывает, что одно и то же слово с приставкой "за" в одних ситуациях проявляет один смысл, в других - другой. Например, слово "запросить" в устойчивых сочетаниях "запросить пощады (мира)" имеет смысл "начала действия" (стал просить), а в прочих случаях имеет смысл "подачи запроса", причём для второго случая характерен другой падеж существительного (как правило, винительный).
Здесь на эту тему была оживлённая дискуссия:
http://forum.lingvo.ru/actualthread.aspx?tid=154289